# Why do All Environments Appear Stopped on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab

All my environments (Deployments > Environments) appear 'Stopped', in GitLab Community Edition 15.1.5.
The Docs state that one needs at least 'Reporter' role; I don't know if I have that, or how to check, but assume I have it.

Edit:  Deployments happen as part of the build, in the Deployment stage of the gitlab ci.

Comment: If you're using "[review apps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/review_apps/)" for creating your environments, they'll automatically be stopped when the MR is merged/delted or when the source branch is deleted. Maybe that's what is happening? Also if you deploy to the same environment multiple times, it's assumed only the latest deployment is active (all others are stopped).

Comment: thanks for the reply; Deployments happen as part of the build, in the Deployment stage of the gitlab ci.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant parts of your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Comment: I have done, as you've advised.

Answer (score 0):

***what follows is potentially a red herring, further tests are required***
I was directed by a colleague, as follows:
(The snippet of gitlab ci yaml that I included was irrelevant, so I'll remove it from the question.
I will include the yaml from our dev environment, it has the same symptom.) The offending part was as follows:

Before - (environment stopped on gitlab)

```
###################### - DEV - Azure Deployment
DEV_deploy_to_azure:
  environment:
    name: DEV_AZURE
    url: https://app-xxxxxx-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/health
  <<: *azure_deployment
  variables:
    DOCKER_TAG: DEV
  when: manual
```

After

```
###################### - DEV - Azure Deployment
DEV_deploy_to_azure:
  <<: *azure_deployment
  environment:
    name: DEV_AZURE
    url: https://app-xxxxxx-dev.azurewebsites.net/api/health
  variables:
    DOCKER_TAG: DEV
  when: manual
```

Here are my colleague's words:
Solution: change the order of the environment-key in the pipeline:

Now all my deployments appear as expected.